# Jquery data-role option is ignored for dynamically created "ul" items

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have created "ul" & "li" elements dynamically in JQuery Mobile. I have assigned data-role="listview" to "ul" element, but the items are displayed as normal html list.

My Code;

```
<body>
....
<div data-role="content">
<button id="btn" onclick="getList()">Click here</button>
<div id="listDiv"></div>
</div>
<script>
$('#btn').on('click',function(){
$('#listDiv').append('<ul data-role="listview"><li data-role="list-divider">Cars</li><li>BMW</li><li>Audi</li><li data-role="list-divider">Flowers</li><li>Lily</li><li>Rose</li></ul>');
$('ul').listview('refresh');
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: What inline `getList()` does when you have click event defined in jQuery?

Comment: `$('ul').listview();` since you are appending a fresh `ul`.

Comment: Check demo and explanation why you should _initialize_ widgets.

Comment: yeah @Omar. I have checked it now.Works fine now.

Comment: Good, I just wanted you to know why it works and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('#listDiv').trigger('create');
```

---

Update

```
$('#listDiv ul').listview();
```

Comment: this works (fix), but still not a 100% correct answer.

Comment: @Omar This will work `$('#listDiv ul').listview();` perfectly .

Comment: @Omar as you said above in the comment OP is creating a new `ul` and appending it to `#listDiv`. So there is need to create `listview` .

Comment: @Gupta: I have added the "update" part as suggested by you. It's working great. Thanks guys for the help.

Answer (score 3):

When jQuery Mobile framework is first initialized, it *enhances* all contents/widgets. However, the dynamically injected elements should be *initialized* / *enhanced* manually by calling *Widget enhancement methods*.

- When you create a new `listview`, you need to call `$("#newList).listview()` to *initialize* it.

  ```
  var newList = '<div data-role="listview" id="new"></ul>';
  $("target").append($(newList).listview());
  ```

  or

  ```
  $("target").append(newList);
  $("#new").listview()
  ```
- When you add elements (`li`) to an existing `listview`, you need to *re-enhance* it using `$("oldList").listview("refresh");`.

  ```
  var elements = '<li>Element</li>';
  $("listview").append(elements).listview("refresh");
  ```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/uUVRy/)**

Answer (score 0):

> First set the data using Jquery . For example

```
$("#id").data(key , value) // like this.
```

> This should not display in your html.